# Trying to find the coordinates of the other two vertices of this triangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This is a personal project of mine, which I've been trying to solve for longer than I care to admit, and am looking for some help in solving this problem.

[image]

First off, you can't assume that this is the only rotation that this triangle will be in, as it can be facing any direction but holds the same structure no matter what.

The coordinates of vertex A is always known, so for simplicity sake let's call it (0,0).

The heading of this triangle is determined by a random point (P) within a distance of 12 (the height of the triangle). I first find the length between these two points:

> len = √((x2-x1)² + (y2-y1)²)

(x1,y1) representing the vertex A, (x2,y2) representing the random point (P) within 12.

Then I extend this imaginary line to have a length of 12 to find the coordinate for the height of the triangle:

> x3 = x1 + (x2 - x1) / len * 12
>
> y3 = y1 + (y2 - y1) / len * 12

This finds points (x3,y3) to finally give the center of the base of the triangle, D, a valid coordinate.

Given that the length of AD is 12, and DC 12, we now find the length of the side AC:

> AC = √(AD² + DC²)

Given that ∠A is 90°, and both ∠B and ∠C being 45°, how can I find the coordinates of vertex B and vertex C?

> ∠A (0,0) and 90°
>
> ∠B (x1,y1) and 45°
>
> ∠C (x2,y1) and 45°
>
> D is the center of the base of the triangle, coordinates solved by extending the distance of a random point (P) to have a length of 12.
>
> △ABC height = 12
>
> length of AD, DA, and DC = 12
>
> length of AB and AC = 16.971

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: Thank you @Hagen von Eitzen for fixing the image to display inside of the post. Sorry, I'm new here obviously.

Comment: So $ABC$ is aright tirangle, $ACD$ and $ADB$ are right isosceles triangles? In that case $AB=AC=12\cdot \sqrt 2$, isn't it? If $D$ is in other directions, you can find $(x_B,y_B)=(x_D-y_D+y_A,,y_D+x_D-x_A)$ and $(x_C,y_C)=(x_D+y_D-y_A,,y_D-x_D+x_A)$.

Comment: What does 'heading' mean in 'heading of this triangle'?

Comment: The heading is a poor word for this, sorry. The triangle can rotate around, with vertex A being at (0,0). So that means that the triangle can be anywhere in the 4 coordinate planes depending on a "random point" I mentioned near the start.

Comment: Also, when you say 'random point within a distance of 12', does this point refer to $D$ in the diagram? And distance from what - the origin? - If so, 'within' is a bit misleading as it suggests the distance is anywhere between $0$ and $12$

Comment: @Shuri2060 random point is like this: http://imgur.com/vBEk6RD

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm still looking at the 2nd part of your response, sorry for no reply

Comment: Suggestion for formulation of problem: We have a triangle with vertices $O$ and two other points $B,C$ lying on the coordinate axes. We also have a random point $P$ with $0<OP<12$. $D$ lies on the hypotenuse of the triangle with $OD\,||\,OP$ and $OD=12$. In addition, $\vec{OP}$ and $\vec{OD}$ have same parity. With this information, find $B$ and $C$.

Comment: @Shuri2060  Yes, that sounds a lot more formal than what I was trying to describe.

Comment: If so, how do you get $∠B = ∠C = 45°$? Addendum to above: also $OD\perp BC$

Comment: ∠A is 90, so ∠B and ∠C have to be 45, no? 90+45+45 = 180, and it isn't a question if the angles are different for ∠B and ∠C.

Comment: What about $30°$ and $60°$? I'm not sure I've fully grasped the problem then. Unless $OD\perp BC$ is not necessary, but instead $\angle B = \angle C$ - in which case what is the meaning of the arc in the image?

Comment: The green is for me from my notes, and simply reused it when posting, but yes, ∠B=∠C. The triangle that you see is how it should look always, but it can rotate around the coordinate plane at vertex A being at (0,0)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you for that, it seems to be working perfectly for my calculations so far.

Comment: I don't know how to mark it as an answer, but that is how you calculate the coordinates for B and C.

Answer (score 0):

You have $AD=BD=CD$ and $\overline{AD}\perp\overline{BC}$, so to find $B$ and $C$ you just need to “step off” a distance of $AD$ in the two directions perpendicular to $\overline{AD}$. In coordinates, the vector $\overrightarrow{AD}$ is $(x_D-x_A,y_D-y_A)$, so $\overrightarrow{DB}=(y_A-y_D,x_D-x_A)$ (note the sign change) and $\overrightarrow{DC}$ its negation. Add these vectors to $D$ to get $$B=(x_D,y_D)+(y_A-y_D,x_D-x_A)=(x_D+y_A-y_D,y_D+x_D-x_A) \\ C=(x_D,y_D)-(y_A-y_D,x_D-x_A) = (x_D-y_A+y_D,y_D-x_D+x_A).$$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Hagen von Eitzen for sharing the very simple way to do this

> B =
>
> > xB = (xD - yD + yA)
> >
> > yB = (yD + xD - xA)
>
> C =
>
> > xC = (xD + yD - yA)
> >
> > yC = (yD - xD + xA)

So, to put this whole thing into practice...

> Vertex A = (-538.1,-41.64)
>
> Random Point (P) = (-548.2,-45.77)

Solve the distance between A and P:

> √((x2-x1)² + (y2-y1)²)
>
> > √(((-548.2)-(-538.1))² + ((-45.77)-(-41.64))²) = 10.911778040265

Then extend the line between A and P to have a distance of 12 to find D, which lies on the hypotenuse of the triangle:

> x3 = x1 + (x2 - x1) / len * 12
>
> > x3 = -538.1 + (-548.2 - (-538.1)) / 10.911778040265 * 12 = -549.20726405475
>
> y3 = y1 + (y2 - y1) / len * 12
>
> > y3 = -41.64 + (-45.77 - (-41.64)) / 10.911778040265 * 12 = -46.181881242188
>
> **D = (-549.20726405475 , -46.181881242188)**

Using the coordinates for A and D, find the coordinate of B and C:

> B =
>
> > xB = (xD - yD + yA)
> >
> > > xB = -549.20726405475 - (-46.181881242188) + (-41.64) = -544.66538281256
> >
> > yB = (yD + xD - xA)
> >
> > > yB = -46.181881242188 + (-549.20726405475) − (-538.1) = -57.289145296938
> > >
> > > > **B = (-544.66538281256 , -57.289145296938)**
>
> C =
>
> > xC = (xD + yD - yA)
> >
> > > xC = -549.20726405475 + (-46.181881242188) - (-41.64) = -553.74914529694
> >
> > yC = (yD - xD + xA)
> >
> > > yC = -46.181881242188 − (-549.20726405475) + (-538.1) = -35.074617187438
> > >
> > > > **C = (-553.74914529694 , -35.074617187438)**

Thank you, everyone, for your help! Truly appreciate it.

Comment: Your initial results for $B$ and $C$ are suspect, and, in fact, can be seen to incorrect in the simple case where $A$ is at the origin. In that case you end up with $B$ off the $x$-axis and $C$ off the $y$-axis. That renders everything else incorrect. Take a look at the other solutions herein, including my own.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe it is much easier to describe the situation using basic vector algebra. This approach also works with any triangle, not just a right triangle.

First, let's call the points $P = ( x_P , y_P )$, $A = ( x_A , y_A )$, $B = ( x_B , y_B )$, and $C = ( x_C , y_C )$, the altitude of the triangle $h$, and $\left\lVert\overline{BC}\right\rVert = 2w$:
[image: Triangle]

In OP's case, $h = 12$ and $w = 12$, but this works for any triangle with positive $h$ and $w$.

First, create an unit vector from $A$ to $P$,
$$\hat{u} = \frac{\overline{PA}}{\left\lVert\overline{PA}\right\rVert}$$
ie.
$$x_U = \frac{x_P - x_A}{\sqrt{(x_P - x_A)^2 + (y_P - y_A)^2}} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$y_U = \frac{y_P - y_A}{\sqrt{(x_P - x_A)^2 + (y_P - y_A)^2}} \tag{2}\label{2}$$

The other unit vector $\hat{v}$ is $\hat{u}$ rotated 90° clockwise:
$$x_V = -y_U \tag{3}\label{3}$$
$$y_V = x_U \tag{4}\label{4}$$

Now, locating $B$ and $C$ is trivial:
$$B = A + h \, \hat{u} + w \, \hat{v} \tag{5}\label{5}$$
$$C = A + h \, \hat{u} - w \, \hat{v} \tag{6}\label{6}$$
or, in other words,
$$x_B = x_A + h \, x_U + w \, x_V = x_A + h \, x_U - w \, y_U \tag{7}\label{7}$$
$$y_B = y_A + h \, y_U + w \, y_V = y_A + h \, y_U + w \, x_U \tag{8}\label{8}$$
$$x_C = x_A + h \, x_U - w \, x_V = x_A + h \, x_U + w \, y_U \tag{9}\label{9}$$
$$y_C = y_A + h \, y_U - w \, y_V = y_A + h \, y_U - w \, x_U \tag{10}\label{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a trigonometric approach. For simplicity, I'm turning the diagram around so that it's in the first quadrant. Everything hinges on the angle

$$\theta=\angle BAD=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y_D}{x_D}\right)$$

You can then readily show that

$$
\angle C=\theta\\
\angle CAD=\angle ABD=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta
$$

Now, by the law of sines for the two triangles,

$$
\frac{AD}{\sin(\pi/2-\theta)}=\frac{BD}{\sin\theta}\\
\frac{AD}{\sin\theta}=\frac{CD}{\sin(\pi/2-\theta)}
$$

Then the hypotenuse

$$H=BC=CD+BD=AD(\tan\theta+\cot\theta)=(\tan\theta+\cot\theta)$$

where $r$ is the radius of the circle. It follows that

$$
AB=H\sin\theta\\
AC=H\cos\theta\\
$$

I have verified these for randomly selected points on the circular arc.

Answer (score 0):

$ABC$ is a right triangle with hypothenuse $24,$ thus the sides have the length $12\sqrt{2}.$

If $B$ lies on $y$-axis and $C$ on $x$-axis as shows your figure, their coordinates are $B(0,12\sqrt 2), C(-12\sqrt 2,0).$

For an arbitrary position of the triangle, still with $A(0,0),$ use the rotation through an angle $\gamma$ about the center $A.$ 
The rotation is represented by the matrix

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos \gamma & -\sin \gamma\\
\sin\gamma & \cos \gamma
\end{matrix}
\right).$$
Note that $\vec{AB}=(0,12\sqrt 2)$ and $\vec{AC}=(-12\sqrt 2,0).$

To obtain the coordinates of arbitrary vertices $B',C',$ multiply the matrix and column vectors ${\vec{AB}}^T$ or ${\vec{AC}^T}.$ This gives

$B'(-12\sqrt2\sin\gamma,12\sqrt2\cos\gamma)$ and $C'=(-12\sqrt2\cos\gamma,-12\sqrt2\sin\gamma).$